# Algorithm for figuring out if two strings are palindromes at a specific index

Tags: python, string

Given two strings, A and B, of equal length, find whether it is possible to split
both strings at the same index such that merging the first part of A and the second
part of B forms a palindrome. Return the location of the split. Palindrome is a word
that reads the same backward as forward.
If the solution can not be found, return -1.

Here is what I have so far

```py
def palindrome(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return None
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        firstStr = str1[i:]
        secondStr = str2[:i]
        if isPalindrome(firstStr+secondStr):
            return i
    return -1


def isPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]


print(palindrome('abcdefgh', 'dasedcba'))
```

My solution returns `-1` for the test case though it should return `4`

I'm not sure what to change to make sure that the correct index is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not taking correctly the first part of the first string and the second part of the second string. Keep in mind that when you slice a string:

```py
>>> s = 'abcdefgh'
>>> s[:4] # this will take the first 4 elements of s
'abcd'
>>> s[4:] # this will take a sub-string from the 5th element at index 4 until the end of s
'efgh'
```

Therefore, you should change your code:

```py
def palindrome(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        raise ValueError('str1 and str2 should have the same length')
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        firstStr = str1[:i]
        secondStr = str2[i:]
        if isPalindrome(firstStr + secondStr):
            return i
    return -1
```

Also keep in mind the following, if both strings `str1` and `str2` do not have the same length, you are returning `None`, so you can just write `return` since that returns `None` implicitly. However, I think that it is better to raise an exception that tells the user that `str1` and `str2` do not have the same length.

Comment: @smac89, I agree with you that it might be needless to check for equality of `str1` and `str2`. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to your problem, you want to merge the first part of A (`str1`) and the second part of B (`str2`), but in your code you're doing the reverse, just switch the slices on `str1` and `str2`:

```
firstStr = str1[:i]   # from the start up to i (first part of str1)
secondStr = str2[i:]  # from i to up the end (second part of str2)
```

Test:

```
def palindrome(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) != len(str2):
        return None
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        firstStr = str1[:i]
        secondStr = str2[i:]
        if isPalindrome(firstStr+secondStr):
            return i
    return -1

def isPalindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

print(palindrome('abcdefgh', 'dasedcba'))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also just be reversing your words and then running your check that way:

reverse_word = word[::-1]